# Compiling the uIP library in Arduino IDE

Tags: c, compilation, arduino

I'm trying to compile a very simple Arduino program that connects to a server and send it the string "ok\n". The program makes extensive use of the uIP library (actually, its a library based on uIP, but it seems to be almost identical). Here is my sketch:

```
#include <uip.h>

void setup() {
  connect_example2();
}

void loop() {
 uip_send("ok\n", 3);
}

void connect_example2(void) {
uip_ipaddr_t ipaddr;
uip_ipaddr(&ipaddr, 192,168,1,100);
uip_connect(&ipaddr, HTONS(8080));
}
```

However, when I compile I get the following error:

```
test.cpp.o: In function `connect_example2()':
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/test.ino:14: undefined reference to `uip_connect(unsigned int (*) [2], unsigned int)'
test.cpp.o: In function `loop':
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/test.ino:8: undefined reference to `uip_send(void const*, int)'
```

Judging by the error, the Arduino IDE is linking the library just fine. What could the problem be?

Comment: In function's documentation: http://weinert-automation.de/files/weAutSys/doxygen/group__uipappfunc.html#gaedd860dbf4565703ccb858e9dc7bb21b , it is stated that you need to define UIP_ACTIVE_OPEN to 1 in uipopt.h. Have you?

Answer (score 0):

The "undefined reference" error implies that, contrary to your statement, the IDE is not linking the library. It's simply finding the header, which means you don't get an undeclared function error. I would guess that the Arduino IDE isn't configured with the library. Have you tried compiling a uIP example sketch to ensure that the library is installed properly?